# Assigning a values to a function argument in c++ in the order which it is defined

Tags: c++, c++17

When passing a value to a function with multiple arguments which contains some default values how would I let my function know that this value is supposed to be for the last argument?

For example in the code

```
 int myFun(int a, int b=2,ofstream &file) {   
    file<<"Hello please write this to a file"<<"\n";   
    int r;   
    r=a/b;   
    return (r);
    }
 
 int main () {   
  ofstream file("input.txt");   
  cout << myFun(12,3,file)<< '\n';   
  cout << myFun(20, ,file) << '\n';  //This doesn't work  
 return 0; 
  }
```

How would I let my program know that the value 4 is supposed to be for C and not for B?

Comment: If you give a default value to a parameter, all the parameters following it must also have default values.

Comment: You can't have parameters without a default after the first defaulted parameter. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8a07beaf0724de2

Comment: Moving the file parameter to front will solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Default arguments have to be provided starting from the right. You cannot have default arguments for the second but none for the third.

One workaround is to encapsulte the parameters in a data structure:

```
struct myFunParameters {
     int a = 0;
     int b = 2;
     std::ofstream& file;
};
```

And change signature to:

```
int myFun(myFunParameters f);
```

The caller can then use the defaults or provide custom values in any order they wish.

Alternatively remove the default arguments and use an overload:

```
 int myFun(int a, int b,ofstream &file);
 int myFun(int a,ostrstream& file) { return myFun(a,2,file); }
```